# Git retains the code that is remotely reverted

Tags: git, github

Our team has two branches, one is `develop` branch, the other is `my-feature` branch. `my-feature` is branched off from `develop`.

One developer has made some changes on `my-feature` branch. Then, he merged it to `develop`. During this procedure, no other developer committed to `my-feature` and `develop`. I pulled the `develop` branch at this point.

Later on, that developer reverted his change from the **remote** `develop` branch.

After that, I did `git pull origin develop` again. But I still see his changes (that previously had been merged then reverted) on my local `develop` , why?

**======= UPDATE ======**

With `git reset origin/develop --hard`, I got my local `develop` the same as the remote one now. But locally, I have a new local branch which was branched off from the `develop` branch that contains that developer's changes. Now I tried `git rebase develop` on my local feature branch, I still see those changes even though the `develop` is now clean (without that developer's changes). How to deal with it now to have my local feature branch be clean?

Comment: Can you see the revert commit in the output of `git log develop`?

Comment: If you dont have any of your own changes on your local develop you can solve your problem with `git reset origin/develop --hard`.

Comment: are you in the `develop` branch?

Comment: yes, I am in develop branch. I don't have my own changes on local develop.

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: If some commit on the `develop` branch was reverted - and your local branch is 1:1 with GitHub's `develop` branch - then you should have that revert commit locally at the head of your local `develop` branch.

Answer (score 2):

You probably care a lot about branch names: `develop` vs `master`, for instance.  But Git doesn't.  Git uses them, so that you can use them, but what Git *cares* about is *commits*.  The real name of each commit is not a *branch name* but rather a *hash ID*.  A hash ID is a big ugly thing, such as `745f6812895b31c02b29bdfe4ae8e5498f776c26`, that's easy for a computer to remember, but way too hard for a human to remember.  When you use a branch name, you're really telling Git: *look up the hash ID for this name.*

If you think about things in Git as "branches" you'll keep getting lost.  Think about things in Git as *commits*, and branch names like `master` and `develop` as human-readable labels that get attached to *one commit at a time* and then moved around.  The *commits* are the (mostly) permanent, solid structure that you can climb around on.  Branch names are merely labels.

To put it another way: the problem here is that branch names *move*.  Over time, branch names change *which* commit they mean.  In this particular case, I think someone "reverted" a commit in the wrong way, although it's not completely clear from what you've posted.  What you need to do is look at the *commit graph*.

#### The commit graph

Every commit, besides having its own unique hash ID to find *that particular* commit, also stores the hash ID of some number of *parent* commits.  Usually there's just one parent.  (Merge commits have two, or sometimes more, but we can ignore them for this answer.)  When you have a simple chain of commits, made one by one, with each child commit pointing back to its parent, you get something we can draw like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the hash ID of your latest commit.  Commit `H` itself stores the hash ID of commit `G`, so from `H`, Git can find `G`'s hash ID, and thus find commit `G` itself.  From there, Git can find `F`'s hash ID, and therefore find commit `F`.

The linking arrows always go backwards: a commit knows its parent hash ID, but the parent does not know what its children are, or will be.  This is because once we make a commit, that commit is completely unchangeable.  There's no way to *add* the child's hash ID: someone made commit `H`, and when they did make `H`, `G` was `H`'s parent.  `G` will always be `H`'s parent.  `H`, now that it's made, must stay exactly as it is.

Let's say *you* now decide to make a new commit, which will get its own unique hash ID but we'll just call it `I`.  Let's draw `I` with `H` as its parent:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I
```

New commit `I` points back to existing commit `H`, but we can't *change* `H`, so `H` cannot point to `I`.

These one-way links, from commits backwards, form a *commit graph*.  Inside this graph, we add labels, which point to one commit at a time.  Let's do that now:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop
            \
             I   <-- newbranch
```

(I've made up the branch name `newbranch` to be *your* branch name, i.e., the one you started from `develop`.)

Here, *you* made new commit `I`, using existing commit `H` that your existing `develop` named.  This is all *before* your co-worker "reverted" his changes.  I've put the word "reverted" in quotes for a reason, here.

#### Branches normally just grow

The normal process of adding commits, in Git, always adds a *new* commit to this graph, just as we did above.  When someone runs `git commit`, what they have, in their Git repository, is some set of existing commits, and some number of labels.  Each label points to exactly *one* commit.  *One* label has the special name `HEAD` attached to it:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, newbranch (HEAD)
```

Running `git commit`–assuming it succeeds of course—means: *make a new commit, assign it a new unique hash ID, make its parent the current commit—in this case `H`—and write it into the big database of all commits ever*.  Then, having made new commit `I`, Git writes the hash ID of this new commit into the *name to which `HEAD` is attached*.  So that's how we get:

```
---F--G--H   <-- develop
          \
           I   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

The ID of the *current* commit is the one we find by looking at whichever branch name `HEAD` is attached to.  Since that is now `newbranch` and `newbranch` now points to commit `I`, commit `I` is now the current commit.

As long as people stick to this process, every branch only ever *grows*.  Let's see how that would work if we ran `git checkout develop` and then made a new commit.  We'd start with:

```
---F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
          \
           I   <-- newbranch
```

so that the *current* commit is `H`.  Then we'd change some files and `git add` and `git commit`.  This would make up some new unique hash ID, that we'll call `J`, and make `J` point back to `H` and then update the current *branch name*, `develop`, to point to new commit `J`, giving:

```
---F--G--H--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
          \
           I   <-- newbranch
```

#### Using `git revert` grows a branch in the usual way

Suppose we now decide that there's something terribly *wrong* with commit `G` and we should back out whatever change `G` made.  We can now run:

```
git revert <hash-of-G>
```

What this does is a little complicated, but we can summarize the action as: *Figure out what's different between the snapshots in commits `F` and `G`.  Reverse-apply those changes, whatever they are, to the snapshot in commit `J`, and make a new commit from the result.*  So now we would have:

```
---F--G--H--J--K   <-- develop (HEAD)
          \
           I   <-- newbranch
```

in which commit `K` "un-does" whatever `G` did.

This would also be true if your co-worker reverted commit `J`: he'd get a new `K` that undoes `J`, instead of a new `K` that undoes `G`.  The snapshot in the new commit `K` would match that in commit `H`, but `K` would be a new commit.

This is pretty clearly *not* what your co-worker did, though, because if he had, you could do your `git rebase` of your branch and everything would have worked.

#### What I think your coworker did

I think that in this case, your co-worker effectively decided: *Hm, commit `H` is bad, let's just get rid of it entirely.*  To do that, *he* ran `git reset --hard` in *his* repository, then did a *force push*.  Let's switch from looking at what you can see in *your* repository, to what he would see in his own repository.  The new branch doesn't exist, and he has not made a bad-commit-`J` yet either, so what we have is this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

(At this point, you've fetched all these commits, and updated your own `develop` so that *your* `develop` names the commit with hash ID `H` too.  You may or may not have created your `newbranch` yet, and commit `I`—your coworker won't be able to tell until you `git push` to send your new commits somewhere other than your own computer.)

Now your co-worker decides that commit `H` is bad.  Instead of using `git revert`, which he *should* do to *add* a new commit, he runs `git reset --hard` to *remove* commit `H` from his `develop`, leaving him with:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

As this drawing shows, commit `H` isn't really *gone* yet, it's just no longer *findable*.  Git finds commits by starting from the branch name, which now points to old commit `G`, and working backwards: the internal arrows never go forwards, only backwards.

Now your coworker uses `git push --force`.  The `--force` is necessary because he's going to have your shared rendezvous Git repository on GitHub move *its* label `develop` backwards in the same way.  This is where things begin to go wrong.  A force-push is OK *if and only if* every user of this name understands that the name might "move backwards" like this, and your co-worker didn't warn you that this is the case.

So, now you run `git fetch` or `git pull` in *your* Git repository.  At this point you had:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, origin/develop
            \
             I   <-- newbranch
```

Your `git fetch` finds that the shared rendezvous Git repository on GitHub now has its `develop` pointing, not to commit `H`, but to commit `G`.  So your Git updates your `origin/develop` to point to `G`:

```
...--F--G   <-- origin/develop
         \
          H   <-- develop
           \
            I   <-- newbranch (HEAD)
```

This means that your `develop` is now *ahead of* the `develop` on the GitHub repository.  If you had run `git push origin develop`, you would have put commit `H` *back on* the `develop` branch.  Fortunately(?) you didn't.  Instead, you found yourself in this situation in which you had an unwanted commit on your own `develop`, so instead, you ran:

```
git checkout develop
```

(which made commit `H` current), then:

```
git reset --hard origin/develop
```

which gave you this:

```
...--F--G   <-- origin/develop, develop (HEAD)
         \
          H
           \
            I   <-- newbranch
```

Here, commit `H`—the "bad" commit your co-worker tried to remove—is *still in your repository*, and is now on *your* branch.

It was on your branch before.  It's just that it was *also* on your `develop` and on `origin/develop`.  Now it's not on `develop` and `origin/develop` any more: it's only on your branch.

#### How to fix this

The only way for you to get rid of `H` is to get rid of `I` too.  This is *very annoying* and is why people should not `git push --force` unless everyone else has agreed to it.

There is a relatively easy and convenient way to get rid of `I` while making a *copy* of `I`, using `git rebase -i`.  In some cases this goes awry, though—especially when someone undid a merge, rather than a simple commit—so I'll illustrate the technique with the more primitive method.

We start by making another new branch at the commit we'd like to have as the parent of `I`.  With our example here, that's commit `G`, but you'll want to run:

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline
```

to get `git log` to draw a representation of the commit graph.  (Or, you can use `gitk` or some graphical viewer like a GUI to show you the graph, as long as the graphical viewer draws it correctly.)  So we'll do this:

```
git checkout -b revised develop
```

to get:

```
...--F--G   <-- origin/develop, develop, revised (HEAD)
         \
          H--I   <-- newbranch
```

Now we'll ask Git to *copy the changes and commit message* from commit `I` to a new commit:

```
git cherry-pick <something that names commit I, e.g., its hash ID>
```

Cherry-pick and revert are very close cousins and do almost the same thing, except that `revert` tries to *undo* something, and cherry-pick tries to *re-do* something.  So this creates a new commit that does the same thing commit `I` did.  Because the new commit is so much *like* `I`, let's call this new commit `I'`:

```
          I'  <-- revised (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G   <-- origin/develop, develop
         \
          H--I   <-- newbranch
```

If that was the only commit we needed to copy, we're done with all the copying.  If you actually had, say:

```
...--F--G   <-- origin/develop, develop, revised (HEAD)
         \
          H--I--J--K   <-- newbranch
```

we'd have to copy `I`, then `J`, then `K`, to get:

```
          I'-J'-K'  <-- revised (HEAD)
         /
...--F--G   <-- origin/develop, develop
         \
          H--I--J--K   <-- newbranch
```

which would take three `git cherry-pick` commands.

Having done the cherry-picking needed to construct the new desired branch, we now have one problem: the name `newbranch` points to the old one and the new name `revised` points to the new one.  We can now delete the old `newbranch`, then rename our `revised` to be called `newbranch`:

```
git branch -D newbranch
git branch -m revised newbranch
```

if the name matters a lot to us.

#### An easier (single) command for fixing things

To make this whole thing a lot easier, we can use one `git rebase command`: `git rebase` means *run git cherry-pick as many times as needed*.  After doing all the cherry-picks onto a temporary branch, `git rebase` yanks the branch name over to the last of the new, copied commits.  The problem here is that Git will think that commit `H` is one of the ones it should copy—commit `H` is, after all, on your branch and *only* your branch—but we want Git to *drop* commit `H`.

There are several ways to deal with this, including both `git rebase -i`—which lets us replace a `pick` (cherry-pick) command with a `drop` command, so as to omit the commit in the new copies—or adding additional arguments to the `git rebase` command, to tell it what *not* to copy.  But I need to finish this answer off, and we haven't actually seen your commit *graph*—your `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` output—so you'd best check that this really matches what happened.  There may be more than one commit to drop!